# Use PNP sensor on NPN input

Tags: circuit-design, electrical

I want to use the IPOS3602 [datasheet iPOS3602](https://www.technosoftmotion.com/products/Download-datasheets.php?FileNo=21)  this is a small motion controller. I have another datasheet which is protected so I can't share it. This datasheet states: The inputs are compatible with NPN type outputs (input must be pulled to GND to change it's default state).
The picture below shows the input circuit for the driver.

My question is I guess the same as [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255670/using-24-v-pnp-switch-on-npn-input) I'm using 24V PNP sensors, could I use a similar NPN circuit to make this workd? I want to use two end switches (24V PNP)

[image: Input circuit]

Comment: I don't see any reason you couldn't use the same additional NPN circuit as shown in the referenced answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MikeP, I furthered my research and contacted the manufacturer. The following circuit should work. This is similar to circuit in the former question.

[image: PNP sensor to NPN input]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUNSJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An opto-isolator solution.*

An opto-isolator solution does the same job with one less component and complete electrical isolation between the two devices.

[image]

*Figure 2. 24 V opto-couplers are available in DIN-rail mounted packages complete with inbuilt current-limiting resistors, indicator LED and, in some cases, reverse polarity protection.*